# What does an overline above a graph mean?

Tags: math, graph-theory, notation

[Specifically in this example][image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9j6L8.png)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematics rather than programming.

Comment: ok sorry :((((((

Comment: It isn't a big deal. As a rule of thumb, if your question can be answered without any code or at least discussion of an algorithm then it probably belongs on [mathematics.se]. The border between the two sites can be fuzzy at times, especially since so many tags are the same (e.g. `graph-theory`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the correct forum to post this, but an overline on a graph means the complement of the graph.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_graph